# How to connect to different oracle instance as sysdba using sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I run sqlplus it connect to orcl2 instance but I need to connect to orcl I can connect to my normal user using this:

```
sqlplus user/passowrd@//localhost:1521/orcl
```

but how can I connect as sysdba? I've try:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba@orcl
```

but it connect to orcl2 instance.

Comment: `sqlplus usr/pwd@orcl as sysdba`, I think

Comment: Also, assuming that `orcl` is a valid sid, you can set the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable to `orcl`, then you should be able to do `sqlplus / as sysdba`

Comment: @sstan it work, you can add this as an answer.

Comment: Which one worked for you? :)

Comment: ORACLE_SID environment variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable to `orcl`.

Then `sqlplus / as sysdba` will connect to `orcl` as expected.